# get a list of tuples with the columns that have only two same strings:

Tags: python

I have the following problem:

In case I want to get the columns of a dataframe which have all same strings I use the code that follows:

Let's create the dataframe first: `df_example1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,2,3]})` . Now let's look for the columns that have exactly the same strings:
`[(i, j) for i,j in combinations(df_example1, 2) if df_example1[i].equals(df_example1[j])]`
The code returns the tuple [('A', 'B')]

My problem is: In case I want to get a tuple of columns which have ONLY two of the strings the same what code should I use? Let's say that my dataframe is the following:
`df_example2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,4],'B':[1,2,3]})` and it should return the tuple [('A', 'B')].

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the *intersection* of both columns to contain two (or more?) values. You can use the [`set` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and its operations for this.

```
df_example2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,4],'B':[1,2,3]})
intersect = s et(df_example2['A']).intersection(df_example2['B'])
# {2, 3}
```

Now, if `intersect` has 2 (or more?) elements, you want to select the tuple `('A', 'B')`.

```
[(i, j) 
    for i,j in combinations(df_example2, 2) 
    if len(set(df_example2[i]).intersection(df_example2[j])) == 2
]
# Or >= 2 if you want 2 or more
# [('A', 'B')]
```

Note: The elements of the columns need to be hashable types to be able to create a set

> But in the end this solution returns nothing if you increase the columns of the dataframe. For example, if `df_example4 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,4], 'B':[1,2,3], 'C':[2,3,5], 'D':[3,5,6]})`, I would expect to get `[('A','B','C'), ('C', 'D')]`. Instead, I get an empty list.

In this case, you need to also change the number of columns you select in `combinations()`. It's easier to write out a function that takes *any* number of sets and returns the intersection of them all:

```
def intersect(cols_list):
    cols_iter = iter(cols_list) # Create an iterator
    r = set(next(cols_iter))    # Set the return value to the first column
    for s in cols_iter: 
        r = r.intersection(s)   # Intersect this with every other column
    return r
```

Let's write the list comprehension as a regular loop first to help us understand what is happening:

```
matching_cols = []
for ncols in range(2, len(df_example4.columns)+1):
    col_names = combinations(df_example4, ncols)
    cols = [df_example4[cname] for cname in col_names]
    if len(intersect(cols)) == 2:
        matching_cols.append(col_names)
```

Or, as a comprehension:

```
[col_names for ncols in range(2, len(df_example4.columns)+1) for col_names in combinations(df_example4, ncols) if len(intersect(df_example4[cname] for cname in col_names)) == 2]
```

Which gives:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C')]
```

Now, we need to remove the pairs that are already part of a bigger combination:

```
final = []
for c in matching_cols:
    sc = set(c)
    exclude = False
    for c2 in matching_cols:
        sc2 = set(c2)
        # If c is a subset of c2 and both aren't equal, then we need to exclude c from the final result
        if sc != sc2 and sc.issubset(sc2): 
            exclude = True
            break
    if not exclude:
        final.append(c)
```

Which gives `[('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C')]`

There is probably a more efficient approach but I will leave that as an exercise for you :)

Comment: Thank you @Pravan :) And if I have the dataframe ```df_example3 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,4],'B':[1,2,3], 'C':[2,3,5]})``` could it return [('A', 'B', 'C')] instead of [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In that case you want combinations of three columns, and a set intersection of all three. Should be fairly straightforward to adapt this code for three columns -- give it a shot and let me know if it doesn't work. @VickyVoukè

Comment: Yeah it works like that. But in the end this solution returns nothing if you increase the columns of the dataframe. For example, if ```df_example4 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,4], 'B':[1,2,3], 'C':[2,3,5], 'D':[3,5,6]}), I would expect to get [('A','B','C'), ('C', 'D')]```. Instead, I get an empty list. :(

Comment: Ah, in that case you want yet another loop to change the number of columns selected by `combinations()`. See my edit @VickyVoukè

Comment: Now it worked!!!! I think I won't bother you anymore. You made my day! :)) Thanks a lot.